# logstash geoip time failed parsing

Tags: java, csv, elasticsearch, logstash, geoip

i'm importing my data to ELK from csv. Everything is working fine except it does not catch the geoip and returns a time format error. Can anybody help me?

```
          type => "netflow"
        columns => ["Time","Src_IP","Src_Port","Det_IP","Dest_port", "Byt", "Pkt","out","Prot","Evt"]
  separator => ","
  }

  date {
        locale => "en"
        match => ["Time", "yyyy-MM-ddHH mm:ss.SSS"]
        timezone => "US/Eastern"
        target => "@timestamp"


}
geoip {
# this will convert ip to longitude-latitude using GeoLiteCity database from Maxmind
    source => "[Src_IP][netflow]"
    fields => ["latitude","longitude"]
    target => "geoip"
    add_field => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "%{[geoip][longitude]}" ]
    add_field => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "%{[geoip][latitude]}"  ]
  }
  mutate {
# this will convert geoip.coordinates to float values
    convert => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "float" ]
  }


##OUTUP


   "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2015-02-21T23:18:22.384Z",
          "type" => "netflow",
          "host" => "Lion",
          "path" => "/var/logstash/2015.02a.csv",
          "Time" => "2015-02-17 10:33:25.340",
        "Src_IP" => "          22.22.22.22",
      "Src_Port" => "      0",
        "Det_IP" => "    111.22.33.22",
     "Dest_port" => "   3389",
           "Byt" => "        1",
           "Pkt" => " 3470047911",
           "out" => "      0",
          "Prot" => " 6    ",
           "Evt" => "  INVALID",
         "geoip" => {}
}
```

> Failed parsing date from field {:field=>"Time", :value=>"2015-02-17
>   10:33:25.342", :exception=>java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid
>   format: "2015-02-17 10:33:25.342" is malformed at " 10:33:25.342",
>   :level=>:warn}

Comment: `match => ["Time", "yyyy-MM-ddHH mm:ss.SSS"]` appears to have a space after the HH instead of a colon, and no space before it.

Comment: Im sorry  it should be yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS

Comment: Is that a typo in your code, or just in this post?

Comment: once I change  geoip filter Src_IP,   source => "Src_IP",  , its giving "IP Field contained invalid IP address" error

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://$SITEURL$/questions/ask) button; you may want to include a link to this one for context. Although asking a long series of related questions is generally not a good idea, so try to make sure you've got all the problems at once.